# play video on thumbnail hover in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want any code works like this  you have static thumbnail as featured image, on hover it will automatically play HTML5 video which is pre-defined for each post (like youtube site)

Comment: you want to do it by code or plugins ?

Comment: i will try both

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

if you want to go with WordPress plugin

1  - [Easy Video Player](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-video-player/) - Free

2  - Media Hovers Wordpress Plugin - Paid

**OR**

If you want to go with coding -

You can add a poster by adding poster="Thumbnail-image.jpg" to the tag

.

```
<video poster="Thumbnail-image.jpg" 
src="yourvideo.mp4" 
id="id0" width="300" onMouseOver="id0.play()" 
onMouseOut="id0.pause()" 
onclick="window.location='yourvideo.mp4';id0.pause()" 
loop title="yourvideo.mp4" >
</video>
```

here Thumbnail-image.jpg is your thumbnail image and yourvideo.mp4 is
video to play on hover.

If the uploader of WordPress does not support .webm, .ogg or .mp4 files

(I haven’t checked that), you can always use an ftp (like Filezilla) program to upload the video’s.

Comment: i want use it in featured image of wordpress post not inside the post

Comment: So you have to find inside wordpress theme folder

Comment: i though you are good with coding. if you are not, Go with Wordpress plugins

Comment: i want different video for each post not specifique video for all

Comment: Using a plugin you can do it. but you have to do this manually

Comment: the name of plugin please

Comment: mark as answer if you got a solution. if any issue feel free to ask