# play video on thumbnail hover in wordpress and show thumbnail on hover

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, hover, thumbnails

Am new here so apologies if this is not allowed.

I was searching for a video on hover option, and found this answer:

[play video on thumbnail hover in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900029/play-video-on-thumbnail-hover-in-wordpress?newreg=64409fea4f3649f89f48f23da94af599)

by @rajendra-singh which works fine but I would like to add the option to display the thumbnail on mouseout.

Code used:

```
<video poster="Thumbnail-image.jpg" 
src="yourvideo.mp4" 
id="id0" width="300" onMouseOver="id0.play()" 
onMouseOut="id0.pause()" 
onclick="window.location='yourvideo.mp4';id0.pause()" 
loop title="yourvideo.mp4" >
</video>
```

Questions:

1. How to display thumbnail again on mouseout
2. How to rewind video on mouseout so that the next time we hover the mouse, the video plays from the beginning

How do I do that? I understand html/css but not js so not able to figure this out on my own.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Please include code if you have any, and be more specific as to what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @DeathWaltz  

The code is exactly the one in the link:  

><video poster="Thumbnail-image.jpg"   
>src="yourvideo.mp4"  
>id="id0" width="300" onMouseOver="id0.play()"  
>onMouseOut="id0.pause()"  
>onclick="window.location='yourvideo.mp4';id0.pause()"  
>loop title="yourvideo.mp4" >  
></video>  
  
And I would like:  
  
1. to display the thumbnail onMouseOut  
  
2. to rewind the video to the start onMouseOut

Comment: Correct. Insert the code, not a link. Links can break or become inaccessible for some users.

Comment: Put that code in your question.